# Visual basic 2010 task bar group

Tags: vb.net

When I have around 3 forms open (when running) in Visual Basic, all of the forms will group into one on the taskbar. However, the name of the group is vshost32.exe; I don't want it to say that. Also, the icon changes.

How can I fix this if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Compile the program into an exe (i.e. MyProgram.exe) and run it directly (not in VB).  It will then group them by your executables name.  When you are running in the IDE, the program is running under the vshost32 process.